# Problems with association of roles on Laravel 8 Project

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm having a problem with the syntax on Laravel 8.

On previous versions, I was able to associate a group of roles on the route to define if user will have access to specific route or not. Basically this is what I used on previous versions.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'customers', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles']], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'CustomerController@getList', 'roles' => ['customers','admin']]);
    Route::get('/add', ['uses' => 'CustomerController@getAdd', 'roles' => ['customers','admin']]);
});
```

Now on Laravel 8, the declaration of controllers and functions was totally different.

```
Route::prefix('customers')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/employ', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController::class, 'getList']);
    Route::get('/employ', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController::class, 'getAdd']);
});
```

I'm having difficult to use the same approach of the older version on new version.

Someone here had the same problem and have some kind of tip to help me solve this issue?

Below follows the middleware that I use to check if auth user have permission to do something.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        if ( $request->user() === null ) {
            return new Response(view('errors.401'));
        }

        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;

        if ( $request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles ) {
           return $next($request);
        }

        return new Response(view('errors.401'));
    }
}
```

Basically what I tried didn't produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The way routes are defined was slight change in laravel 8 if im not sure you want to practice the way of handling updated version of laravel.

Use this code:

```php
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole;

Route::middleware(['auth', CheckRole::class])->prefix('customers')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@getList')->middleware('roles:customers,admin');
    Route::get('/add', 'CustomerController@getAdd')->middleware('roles:customers,admin');
});
```

Now you can use the middleware apply method in group functions.